# How to know what URL points to a specific tile when using a WMS?

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, tiles, url

I can view the tiles provided by a WMS service using QGIS. I add this: https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jorddjupsmodell URL as a WMS layer, I get this view:

[image]

(More info on URL source: [here](https://apps.sgu.se/geolagret/GetMetaDataById?id=4b1ce5a5-a403-4a22-b0b3-11c9e53d9c43&showmetadataview))

Inspecting the source of some websites, I can discover URLs pointing to single tiles. Ie if I go to this link in my browser:

https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_nib_web_mercator_wmts_v2?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=Nibcache_web_mercator_v2&STYLE=default&FORMAT=image/jpgpng&TILEMATRIXSET=default028mm&TILEMATRIX=17&TILEROW=38688&TILECOL=69278

I get this image:

[image]

How can I know what URL points to a specific tile, if I have only the URL for the WMS service, as in the above case? I believe this is the same question as asking what requests QGIS sends exactly to the WMS server, to get a specific tile.

I would like to have a URL which I can paste in my browser and get a tile for a specific zoom level, row and column (= do what QGIS does, retrieve a specific tile), something like:

[https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jorddjupsmodell?something1{z}something2{x}something3{y}](https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jorddjupsmodell?something1%7Bz%7Dsomething2%7Bx%7Dsomething3%7By%7D)

I am looking for something1, something2, something3.

Comment: WMS doesn't support tile schematas - that's what the WM**T**S or TMS protocols are for. The example URL you posted states its protocol to be WMTS. WMS pulls image data by bounding box URL parameters.

Comment: So the URL I am looking for does not exist, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WMS has no concept of tiling or zoom levels.  A client such as QGIS/OpenLayers can spoof tiling, by splitting up the area of interest and sending multiple GetMap requests.  This can sometimes cause issues (repeated labelling for example) because a WMS server doesn't maintain session state (every request is regarded as separate from a previous one).

A map image is fetched using a `GetMap` request, you need to specify `height` and `width` in pixels, a bounding box (`BBOX`), in minx,miny,maxx,maxy order where for the latest version `1.3.0` x is the first listed axis and y the second according to the official coordinate reference system (see for example epsg.org for EPSG codes) as specified in the `CRS`. You need to specify one or more `LAYERS` and the output `format` and a style per layer `styles`.

For QGIS you specify the endpoint of the service.

Something like: `https://ogc.xxx.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_BGS-HPA_Radon_Potential/ows?`

QGIS will make a GetCapabilities request to determine layer and style names, supported CRS, data extents, etc and presents that to the user in a readable format.

A user then adds the layer they want, selects the style and QGIS works out the rest of the information according to the map view